# Rebuild xDB Index in Solr

Tags: xdb, solr

I'm attempting to get analytics working on a Sitecore 9.0 install. After various issues with connection strings being wrong, trackers not initialising I've got to a point where I'm fairly sure the xDB solr index isn't doing whatever it is it actually does.

So I've tried to rebuild it following these instructions:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html

Solr was actually having an issue with the index which already existed so I've created 2 new index's (xDB and xDB rebuild) and then updated the connection string and run the request rebuild command on `XConnectSearchIndexer`. But it errors :(

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker>XConnectSearchIndexer -rr
    Requesting rebuild.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
       at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
       at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.d__21.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.d__20`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.d__19`1.MoveNext()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
       at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.IndexerHostAppDomainBridge.RequestRebuild() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerAppDomainHost.cs:line 170
       at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.IndexerHostAppDomainBridge.RequestRebuild()
       at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.RequestRebuild() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\Program.cs:line 131
       at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the Solr server?

Comment: It seems that Solr index is not found. Can you check if solrCore connection string is correct in xconnect_instance\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config?

Comment: Is your rebuild core named exactly like the SOLR core with _rebuild at the end. So if your xDB core is sitecore_xdb, the rebuild is sitecore_xdb_rebuild. Also verify the primary core name in the connectionstrings.config. It is the solrCore connection string.

Comment: My solr core is called cg_xdb and there is another called cg_xdb_rebuild. In the connection string file the connection string is set to

<add name="solrCore" connectionString="https://localhost:8983/solr/cg_xdb" />

If I try going to that in a browser then I get Problem accessing /solr/cg_xdb. Reason: Not found.

If I go to https://localhost:8983/solr/#/cg_xdb then I get the core admin page. Should it be set to the later or is there another issue?

Comment: Have you setup Solr with HTTPS? Then, add https:// to the beginning of your connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at the wrong connection string file.

The xConnect Site has a connectiong string located at:

\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config

But the index worker you run to do a rebuild has it's own connectiong string at:

\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config

Answer (score 0):

Run fiddler and then run the command.

This way you can see precisely what url the indexer is running against and what kind of post it is doing.